# Code-First Entity Framework polymorphic relationships if one derived type contains another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, data-modeling

Using EF6 Code-First in a party-planning app, I'm trying to model a `Party` entity with an `Attendees` property (e.g. `ICollection<???> Attendees`) where attendees can either be a `Person` or a `Family` and where a `Family` contains a collection of `Person` instances.

I've read through the helpful series of Code-First modeling articles here: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-1-introduction-and-basic-concepts. If attendees were `Dog` or `Cat` or some other mutually-exclusive, unrelated types then the advice in those articles is clear.

But what's the right way to model a collection of entities that may be related to each other like `Person` and `Family` are?

EDIT: The main problem I'm trying to solve here is how to model the `ICollection<???> Attendees` property of the `Party` entity.  Specifically, the articles linked above give advice (quoted below) about choosing a modeling strategy for inheritance. In my use-case, one derived type (`Family`) contains instances from another derived type (`Person`). Does this suggest that I should use one of the strategies over the other?  Or is this fact not very relevant to choice of modeling strategy?

> There are three different approaches to representing an inheritance
>   hierarchy:
>
> - Table per Hierarchy (TPH): Enable polymorphism by denormalizing the SQL schema, and utilize a type discriminator column that holds type
>     information.
> - Table per Type (TPT): Represent "is a" (inheritance) relationships as "has a" (foreign key) relationships.
> - Table per Concrete class (TPC): Discard polymorphism and inheritance relationships completely from the SQL schema.
>
> <snip>
>
> Before we get into this discussion, I want to emphasize that there is
>   no one single "best strategy fits all scenarios" exists. As you saw,
>   each of the approaches have their own advantages and drawbacks. Here
>   are some rules of thumb to identify the best strategy in a particular
>   scenario:
>
> - If you don’t require polymorphic associations or queries, lean toward TPC—in other words, if you never or rarely query for
>     BillingDetails and you have no class that has an association to
>     BillingDetail base class. I recommend TPC (only) for the top level of
>     your class hierarchy, where polymorphism isn’t usually required, and
>     when modification of the base class in the future is unlikely.
> - If you do require polymorphic associations or queries, and subclasses declare relatively few properties (particularly if the main
>     difference between subclasses is in their behavior), lean toward TPH.
>     Your goal is to minimize the number of nullable columns and to
>     convince yourself (and your DBA) that a denormalized schema won’t
>     create problems in the long run.
> - If you do require polymorphic associations or queries, and subclasses declare many properties (subclasses differ mainly by the
>     data they hold), lean toward TPT. Or, depending on the width and depth
>     of your inheritance hierarchy and the possible cost of joins versus
>     unions, use TPC.
>
> By default, choose TPH only for simple problems. For more complex
>   cases (or when you’re overruled by a data modeler insisting on the
>   importance of nullability constraints and normalization), you should
>   consider the TPT strategy. But at that point, ask yourself whether it
>   may not be better to remodel inheritance as delegation in the object
>   model (delegation is a way of making composition as powerful for reuse
>   as inheritance). Complex inheritance is often best avoided for all
>   sorts of reasons unrelated to persistence or ORM. EF acts as a buffer
>   between the domain and relational models, but that doesn’t mean you
>   can ignore persistence concerns when designing your classes.

Comment: whats your problem ? each Family contains `0` or mor `Person` , and you just add some Fluent to do it

Comment: @UthmanRahimi side note: Family is family if it has at least 2 persons :D

Comment: @UthmanRahimi - The main problem I'm trying to solve here is how to model the `ICollection<???> Attendees` property of the `Party` entity.  I edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

your model look like this :

```
 public class Family
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
public ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }

}
public class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Family Family { get; set; }
}
```

and add some config like this:

```
   HasRequired(row => row.Family).WithMany().HasForeignKey(row => row.FamilyId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```